# Clearing all data from table, but keeping columns/structure

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm using PHPMyAdmin but can use MySQL if it's easier that way, I have quite a large database I'm using for a project that will be updated by uploading .csv files.
However this CSV file will add duplicate data every time, which is no good. 
I'm looking to delete all content on the table, but keep the structure and column titles.
Whats the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `truncate table_name` ?

Comment: use `truncate ` in mysql

Comment: export only structure of data with drop table if exist

Comment: truncating individual table will take time if database is too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TRUNCATE [TABLE] tbl_name
```

Go through [TRUNCATE TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps :

```
1.) Go to phpmyadmin
2.) Select db
3.) choose Operations tab.
4.) look for "copy database to" panel
5.) give new database name
6.) select Structure only radio button
7.) select CREATE DATABASE before copying
8.) hit Go button
```

This will create new database with schema only, which you can rename to your original table name later.
[image]